Roslyn compilation fail loading dependencies
I'm opening a C# solution/projetcs (csprj) with Roslyn but the compilation fails when resolving all types coming from nuget dependencies.
How to restore packages and/or tell Roslyn to load all binaries in bin folder ?
The solution/projetcs build and run ok in VisualStudio.

rpsyln is a tool to check your code not a ide like msbuild

in order to resolve types roslyn needs to load external assemblies, or not?

That's what all the MSBuild tooling does. Try using aka.ms/msbuildlog to see how MSBuild is bringing all that stuff into the compiler.
